# finding duplicates in a list using LEN?

Tags: python, list, function

Okay, so the assignment is:

> Associate True with the variable has_dups if the list list1 has any duplicate >elements (that is if any element appears more than once), and False otherwise.

Okay, so did some searching and found a couple different ways to  search for the presence of duplicates. But here is where it gets... weird.

The system for my homework is telling me these methods are wrong and that I should be using LEN.

Um... how will knowing the length of a list help me find out if there are duplicates in the list? Like if I have

```
myList = [200,200,201,202]
```

okay Len will tell me that I have 4 items in there. So... what does that do to help me find duplicates?

Comment: that doesn't actually answer my question as that just tells me the code to perform the function, it doesn't explain why len is used or how it helps in the problem. The critical point would be using the set function and also explaining what set does.

Comment: yeah, and if this were like a 2nd or 3rd course in a particular language, I could just abide by that. But it's not. From my understanding this isn't even a 1st course in python specific programming, this is an introduction to programming concepts. As a first class in general programming, why would I assume that there's a pre-built function to remove duplicate items from a list? I mean while I'm at it should I also assume that there's a pre-built function to generate a list of lists sorted alphabetically by their first element?

Comment: unless I missed something, doesn't that only sort a single list's contents?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157596/discussion-between-michael-cividanes-and-cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `set` converts a passed in `list` into a `set`, which does not maintain duplicates. Thus, you can do the following:

```
def hasDuplicates(mylist):
    if len(mylist) == len(set(mylist)):
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: yeah, the book doesn't mention the set function at all. Which I wouldn't have an issue with with if this were say a class in a python specific course and we didn't occasionally dip our toes into java, and php.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the length of the set of the list against the length of the list itself:

```
if len(set(myList)) < len(myList):
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

A set has unique elements, meaning no duplicates. So if you have a duplicate, the length of your set(list) will be different than the list.

```
if len(mylist) != len(set(mylist)):
    return True
return False
```

Comment: ah the set function. Would have been nice for the book to mention that function. I mean I get that there is a documentation that lists out the functions, but this is an introduction to programming. It only uses python as a vehicle for programming concepts. Am I wrong for expecting the book to mention something like "Two functions that are handy when dealing with lists are the LEN function, which returns of the length of the list and the SET function that returns the number of unique items in a list." ?

Comment: @MichaelCividanes At the end, you learned it so that's the important thing :)

Comment: You don't need the else, since the `return True` acts like a `break`.

Comment: @ᴬᴶᵁᴾᴾᴬᴸ you are right. adopted the answer.